# Minimize angle in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to figure out how to minimize a scalar in pytorch that represents the angle of an axis/angle rotation. My `target` is a sample set of 3D vectors, my `input` is the `target` rotated by a particular axis/angle rotation (plus some gaussian noise). The axis is known and fixed. I want to find the angle using pytorch.

What I have so far is this `nn.Module`:

```
class AngleModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AngleModel, self).__init__()
        self.angle = nn.Parameter(Variable(torch.Tensor([0.0]), requires_grad=True))
        self.qw = torch.cos(self.angle / 2.)
        self.qx = 0.0
        self.qy = 0.0
        self.qz = torch.sin(self.angle / 2.)

    def forward(self, input):
        matrix_np = transform_from_pq([0, 0, 0, self.qw, self.qx, self.qy, self.qz])
        matrix = torch.from_numpy(matrix_np)
        input_ext = torch.cat((input, torch.ones(input.size(0)).reshape(-1, 1)), 1)
        output = torch.matmul(input_ext.float(), matrix.float())
        return output[:, :3]
```

However using this in an optimizer fails because `model.parameters()` returns an empty list (i.e. "empty" generator).

I'm completely new to pytorch. What am I doing wrong?

## Relevant code

Initialization:

```
def _init_model(self):
    self.model = AngleModel()
    self.crit = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    l_rate = 0.01
    print(list(self.model.parameters()))
    self.optim = torch.optim.SGD(self.model.parameters(), lr = l_rate)
    self.epochs = 2000
```

Learning function:

```
for epoch in range(self.epochs):
    inputs = torch.from_numpy(normalize(input))
    labels = torch.from_numpy(normalize(target))
    _x = Variable(inputs, requires_grad = True) # without it complains about no grad_fn
    _y = Variable(labels)
    self.optim.zero_grad()

    outputs = self.model.forward(_x)
    loss = self.crit(outputs, _y)
    loss.backward()
    self.optim.step()
    print("Epoch %6d loss %05.3f; %s" % (epoch, loss.data[0], self.model.angle))
```

## Update 1:

- Code of the Module updated
- Surrounding code added
- **This at least does not throw any errors anymore but also does not optimize `angle`**

Comment: Can you show relevant code were you call both your initializer, as well as the training loop?

Comment: Done. It runs now without errors but it doesn't optimize `angle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the necessary changes to the AngleModel class to make it work:

```
class AngleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AngleModel, self).__init__()
        self.angle = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.0))

    def forward(self, input):
        qw = torch.cos(self.angle / 2.)
        qx = 0.0
        qy = 0.0
        qz = torch.sin(self.angle / 2.)

        matrix = torch.zeros(3, 3)

        matrix[0, 0] = 1. - 2. * qy ** 2 - 2. * qz ** 2
        matrix[1, 1] = 1. - 2. * qx ** 2 - 2. * qz ** 2
        matrix[2, 2] = 1. - 2. * qx ** 2 - 2. * qy ** 2

        matrix[0, 1] = 2. * qx * qy - 2. * qz * qw
        matrix[1, 0] = 2. * qx * qy + 2. * qz * qw

        matrix[0, 2] = 2. * qx * qz + 2 * qy * qw
        matrix[2, 0] = 2. * qx * qz - 2 * qy * qw

        matrix[1, 2] = 2. * qy * qz - 2. * qx * qw
        matrix[2, 1] = 2. * qy * qz + 2. * qx * qw

        output = torch.matmul(input, matrix)
        return output
```

Among others the main reason that it hadn't been working before was that the graph wasn't consistent due to the intermediate use of numpy. Furthermore the quaternion components qw..qz had been calculated only once in the `__init__` method. Their calculation had to move to the forward step too.